# How to explain req/s difference between yourkit and gatling

Tags: gatling, yourkit

I use gatling to make some performance tests.

On gatling report, I see a mean req/s : 80 but on yourkit performance charts, I see JSP/Servlet request count 300 req/s

Why is there such a gap between both figures ?

Comment: Any chance Yourkit also count forwards, so a single HTTP request counts for several Servlet hits?

Comment: Is forward between servlet filter a possible explanation ?